# Pandas: Multiple Pivots for Key Value Pairs... Faster way?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

### How can I transform the first table into the second table (fast and < 8 GB RAM)?

I have data that's stored in a database in a "key-value pair" format.  When I query the data, I get back this "flattened" kind of table, and I need to unflatten it by essentially pivoting each pair of key-value columns.  It's easier to understand if you look at my example tables below.

Unlike other related questions, I have some different rules/restrictions:

- I don't know which keys, values, or key-value pairs will be missing before I query the data
- key-value column names are always identified by "KEY_###" and "VALUE_###" where ### is some number
- the ### number identifies the pair (e.g., KEY_1 pairs with VALUE_1; KEY_2 does not pair with VALUE_3)
- the KEY's are always alphanumeric characters or missing
- the VALUE's are always numbers or missing
- **not all rows have every key-val pair**  (e.g., in table below, entry_ID B has they key N, but A does not)
- sometimes there is a key but the value is missing (e.g., in table below, KEY_4 is not missing but VALUE_4 is missing)
- if there is a non-missing value, then there will be a non-missing key
- **There may be more than 1 unique key name in a key column** (e.g., KEY_0 has N and O)
- If a key shows up in one key column, it will not be in any other key column (e.g., KEY_0 has both N and O, but neither show up in any other KEY_### column)

To bring down the level of abstraction... think of my data as representing the outcomes of a battery of tests on unique samples where not all samples get the same tests.  The row entry_ID represents a unique sample.  The key represents one of the tests, and the value is the outcome of that test.  Not all samples get the same tests.  Some samples get a test, but don't complete, so the outcome is missing. For example, in table below, sample A got tests P and Q, but sample B only got test N.

However, the tests change with time, but the database does not.  So tests and outcomes are uploaded into the same named columns in the database.  This prevents me from simply using changing the column name (e.g., for KEY_1/VALUE_1 I could change VALUE_1 to "P" and be done, but it would not work for KEY_0/VALUE_0).  The examples below is a simplified and smaller case.

My typical queries will be at least 10k rows with at least 300 key-val pair columns having more than 300 unique keys that need to be pivoted into a more reasonable format for analysis.  They keys are much longer strings and the values are floats... hence my question.  Thanks!

### ***First table:***

`i  entry_ID KEY_0  VALUE_0 KEY_1  VALUE_1 KEY_2  VALUE_2 KEY_3  VALUE_3 KEY_4  VALUE_4
0         A  None      NaN     P    183.0     Q    238.0  None      NaN     R      NaN
1         B     N    886.0  None      NaN  None      NaN  None      NaN     R      NaN
2         C     N    156.0     P    905.0     Q    566.0  None      NaN     R      NaN
3         D     N    843.0     P    396.0  None      NaN  None      NaN     R      NaN
4         E  None      NaN  None      NaN     Q    118.0  None      NaN     R      NaN
5         F     N    719.0     P    721.0     Q    526.0  None      NaN     R      NaN
6         G     N    894.0     P    136.0     Q    438.0  None      NaN     R      NaN
7         H  None      NaN     P    646.0  None      NaN  None      NaN     R      NaN
8         I     N    447.0     P    978.0     Q    458.0  None      NaN     R      NaN
9         J  None      NaN  None      NaN     Q    390.0  None      NaN     R      NaN
10        K     O    843.0     P    745.0     Q    107.0  None      NaN     R      NaN
11        L     O    882.0  None      NaN  None      NaN  None      NaN     R      NaN
12        M     O    382.0     P    876.0     Q    829.0  None      NaN     R      NaN`

### ***Second table:***

`i  entry_ID      N      O      P      Q
0         A    NaN    NaN  183.0  238.0
1         B  886.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
2         C  156.0    NaN  905.0  566.0
3         D  843.0    NaN  396.0    NaN
4         E    NaN    NaN    NaN  118.0
5         F  719.0    NaN  721.0  526.0
6         G  894.0    NaN  136.0  438.0
7         H    NaN    NaN  646.0    NaN
8         I  447.0    NaN  978.0  458.0
9         J    NaN    NaN    NaN  390.0
10        K    NaN  843.0  745.0  107.0
11        L    NaN  882.0    NaN    NaN
12        M    NaN  382.0  876.0  829.0`

---

Reproducible example to create the First Table above (requires Python 3, pandas, and numpy, tqdm is optional)...

```py
import pandas, string, itertools, numpy, time, os
#from tqdm import tqdm

SOME_LETTERS = string.ascii_uppercase
N_KEYVAL_PAIRS = 100
SCALABLE = 3

entry_ID = [''.join(x) for x in list(itertools.permutations(SOME_LETTERS[:13], r=SCALABLE))] # for first 13 letters, n=154440 with r=5
source_keys = [''.join(x) for x in list(itertools.permutations(SOME_LETTERS[13:], r=SCALABLE))] # for first 13 letters, n=154440 with r=5

dick = dict()
dick['entry_ID'] = entry_ID

value_col_names = ['VALUE_' + str(x) for x in range(N_KEYVAL_PAIRS)]
key_col_names = ['KEY_' + str(x) for x in range(N_KEYVAL_PAIRS)]

list_of_cols = ['entry_ID']
source_key_count = 0
#for keycol, valcol in zip(tqdm(key_col_names), value_col_names):
for keycol, valcol in zip(key_col_names, value_col_names):
    dummy_values = numpy.random.randint(1, high=1000, size=len(entry_ID), dtype='l')
    n_not_null = int(len(entry_ID) * 0.75) # about 25% data is null
    n_nulls = len(entry_ID) - n_not_null
    dum_vals = numpy.concatenate((numpy.full(n_nulls, numpy.nan), dummy_values[:n_not_null]))
    numpy.random.shuffle(dum_vals) # in place!

    dummy_keys = numpy.full(len(dum_vals), source_keys[source_key_count], dtype=object)
    if numpy.isnan(dum_vals[0]):
        source_key_count = source_key_count + 1
        dum_keys = numpy.concatenate((dummy_keys[:n_not_null],
                                     numpy.full(n_nulls, source_keys[source_key_count], dtype=object)))
        #print('yes')
    else:
        dum_keys = dummy_keys
    numpy.place(dum_keys, numpy.isnan(dum_vals), [None]) # in place!

    source_key_count = source_key_count + 1    
    dick[keycol] = dum_keys
    dick[valcol] = dum_vals
    list_of_cols.append(keycol)
    list_of_cols.append(valcol)

## Add example of both empty
empty_val = numpy.full(len(entry_ID), numpy.nan)
empty_key = numpy.full(len(entry_ID), None, dtype=object)
empty_k_col = 'KEY_' + str(N_KEYVAL_PAIRS + 0)
empty_v_col ='VALUE_' + str(N_KEYVAL_PAIRS + 0)
dick[empty_k_col] = empty_key
dick[empty_v_col] = empty_val
list_of_cols.append(empty_k_col)
list_of_cols.append(empty_v_col)

## Add example of empty val with key
emptyv_val = numpy.full(len(entry_ID), numpy.nan)
notempty_key = numpy.full(len(entry_ID), source_keys[source_key_count], dtype=object)
notempty_k_col = 'KEY_' + str(N_KEYVAL_PAIRS + 1)
emptyv_v_col ='VALUE_' + str(N_KEYVAL_PAIRS + 1)
dick[notempty_k_col] = notempty_key
dick[emptyv_v_col] = emptyv_val
list_of_cols.append(notempty_k_col)
list_of_cols.append(emptyv_v_col)


my_data = pandas.DataFrame(dick)
my_data = my_data[list_of_cols]    

#print(my_data.to_string()) # printing can take some time
```

---

Here is my hacky attempt. It works (I think), but it takes so long, especially as the size of the table grows.  I don't know what this is in big O, but it's bad.  Like several minutes for my real data of 20k rows and 300 key-val pairs. And it consumes lots of RAM.

Run this snippet after the code above...

```py
### PARSE KEY-VALUE PAIRS
# find KV pair columns
df_tgt = my_data
list_KEY_colnames = sorted(list(df_tgt.filter(regex='^KEY_[0-9]{1,3}$').columns))
list_VALUE_colnames = sorted(list(df_tgt.filter(regex='^VALUE_[0-9]{1,3}$').columns))

new_list_KEY_colnames = list_KEY_colnames
new_list_VALUE_colnames = list_VALUE_colnames
allkeys_withnan = pandas.unique(df_tgt[new_list_KEY_colnames].values.ravel()) # assume dupe names from multiple name cols will never be in the same row
allkeys = allkeys_withnan[pandas.notnull(allkeys_withnan)]
df_kv_parsed = pandas.DataFrame(index=df_tgt.index, columns=allkeys) # init

print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + "\tSTARTING PIVOTING\t{}".format(str(os.getpid())))

##### START PIVOTING EACH PAIR ONE BY ONE UGH
#for each_key, each_value in zip(tqdm(new_list_KEY_colnames), new_list_VALUE_colnames):
for each_key, each_value in zip(new_list_KEY_colnames, new_list_VALUE_colnames):    
    df_single_col_parsed = df_tgt.loc[:, [each_key, each_value]].dropna().pivot(columns=each_key, values=each_value)
    df_kv_parsed[df_single_col_parsed.columns.values] = df_single_col_parsed

print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + "\tDONE PIVOTING\t{}".format(str(os.getpid())))

##### KILL ORIGINAL KV PAIRS
df_tgt.drop(list_KEY_colnames, axis=1, inplace=True)
df_tgt.drop(list_VALUE_colnames, axis=1, inplace=True)  

##### MERGE WITH ORIGINAL AND THEN SAVE
df_fully_parsed = pandas.concat([df_tgt, df_kv_parsed], axis=1, ignore_index=False)
print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + "\tDONE MERGING\t{}".format(str(os.getpid())))

## REMOVE NULL COLUMNS
df_fully_parsed.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Is there any way you can reduce this into a reproducible example? This is near impossible to recreate.

Comment: Did you get an error running my code? I am using python 3 and you need to have pandas and numpy installed sorry.